# Getting subclasses of a sealed trait

Tags: scala, scala-macros, shapeless, scala-reflect

Is it possible (via macros, some form of Shapeless automagic or otherwise) to obtain a list of the subclasses of a sealed trait:

- At compile time?
- At runtime?

Comment: Yes. We are using https://github.com/julienrf/play-json-variants, which does that you can use it as a reference

Comment: @mavarazy Thanks for this. The code is quite dependent on the Play framework and its not readily apparent (to me anyway) how to factor out the minimum required functionality: would you care to post a self-contained variant of the `baseAndVariants' etc functionality as an answer?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You don't need any 3rd party library to do this:

```
sealed trait MyTrait

case object SubClass1 extends MyTrait
case object SubClass2 extends MyTrait

import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}

val tpe = ru.typeOf[MyTrait]
val clazz = tpe.typeSymbol.asClass
// if you want to ensure the type is a sealed trait, 
// then you can use clazz.isSealed and clazz.isTrait
clazz.knownDirectSubclasses.foreach(println)
```

Output:

> object SubClass1
>
> object SubClass2

Comment: Thanks - this works at object scope, but doesn't appear to work inside a function: under Scala 2.11.7, I get:
* No TypeTag available for this.MyTrait
 * not enough arguments for method typeOf: (implicit ttag: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[this.MyTrait])reflect.runtime.universe.Type. Unspecified value parameter ttag.

Comment: How do you mean by `inside a function`? Can you edit the question with your code?

Comment: now sorted: in my particular use case (calling the above functionality inside a generic function) merely requires a TypeTag so that  ru.typeOf can be invoked on the generic type.