# Type-level Set for Algebraic Data Type

Tags: scala, abstract-syntax-tree, shapeless, type-level-computation

This is partly duplicate of this question: [Getting subclasses of a sealed trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534002/getting-subclasses-of-a-sealed-trait), but answer suggests runtime-reflection which is inappropriate for me and I would like to know if it is possible on compilation-time, probably using Shapeless.

So, having this ADT:

```
sealed trait ColumnAttribute
case class Default(value: String) extends ColumnAttribute
case class Identity(seed: Int, step: Int) extends ColumnAttribute
case class Encode(encoding: CompressionEncoding) extends ColumnAttribute
case object DistKey extends ColumnAttribute
```

How can I get something like `Option[Default] :: Option[Identity] :: Option[Encode] :: Option[DistKey] :: HNil`?

More specific question (probably I'm looking for wrong solution).
Having above AST plus following class, how can I be sure in compile-time that `Column` will not get constructed with more than one `Encode` or `DistKey` or other `ColumnAttribute`.

```
case class Column(columnName: String, dataType: DataType, columnAttributes: Set[ColumnAttribute], columnConstraints: Set[ColumnConstraint])
```

**UPD**: `columnAttributes` should contain only one value of particular subtype, but can contain several values of distinct subtypes.

So, this pseudo-code should be correct:

`columnConstraint = Default("foo") :: DistKey :: Identity(1,2) :: HNil`

But this should fail:

`columnConstraint = Default("foo") :: Default("bar") :: HNil`

Comment: May be missing the point here but add a custom apply method for Column? Validating on construction?

Comment: Well yeah, I already thought about it. Because there's too many ways to construct invalid value (like negative `step`) even not taking in account these sets, so overall it probably doesn't worth it. But question is still valid just in sake of curiosity.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying, but since you mention shapeless and even provide an example: that HList of Options is not really a fair representation of the ADT. HLists are products, you need a coproduct: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#coproducts-and-discriminated-unions

Comment: Hey @pedrofurla! For me it still looks more like a product. Because coproduct assumes we have a value which is `DistKey` *or* `Encode` *or* another `ColumnAttribute`, but what I need is (probably empty) product of optional `DistKey` *and* optional `Encode` etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we represent `columnAttributes` in `Column` as an `HList`, we first need to constrain the `HList` elements to be subtypes of `ColumnAttribute` and be distinct.

We can use the [hlist constraints](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/hlistconstraints.scala) `LUBConstraint` and `IsDistinctConstraint` to achieve this.

```
import shapeless.{Default => _, _}
import LUBConstraint._
import IsDistinctConstraint._

def acceptOnlyDistinctAttributes
  [L <: HList : <<:[ColumnAttribute]#λ : IsDistinctConstraint](l: L): L = l
```

Now we need to constraint the `HList` so it can not contain both `Encode` and `DistKey`, unfortunately we need to write this type class ourselves.

We can use `=:=` to check the first element and the `NotContainsConstraint` to check if the tail doesn't contain the other type.

```
trait OnlyOneOfConstraint[L <: HList, A, B] extends Serializable

object OnlyOneOfConstraint {

  def apply[L <: HList, A, B]
    (implicit ooo: OnlyOneOfConstraint[L, A, B]): OnlyOneOfConstraint[L, A, B] = ooo

  type OnlyOneOf[A, B] = {
    type λ[L <: HList] = OnlyOneOfConstraint[L, A, B]
  }

  implicit def hnilOnlyOneOf[A, B] = new OnlyOneOfConstraint[HNil, A, B] {}

  // head is A, so tail cannot contain B
  implicit def hlistOnlyOneOfA[H, T <: HList, A, B](implicit
    ncB: T NotContainsConstraint B, 
    eq: A =:= H,
    oooT: OnlyOneOfConstraint[T, A, B]
  ) = new OnlyOneOfConstraint[H :: T, A, B] {}

  // head is B, so tail cannot contain A
  implicit def hlistOnlyOneOfB[H, T <: HList, A, B](implicit
    ncA: T NotContainsConstraint A, 
    eq: B =:= H,
    oooT: OnlyOneOfConstraint[T, A, B]
  ) = new OnlyOneOfConstraint[H :: T, A, B] {}

  // head is not A or B
  implicit def hlistOnlyOneOf[H, T <: HList, A, B](implicit
    neqA: A =:!= H,
    neqB: B =:!= H,
    oooT: OnlyOneOfConstraint[T, A, B]
  ) = new OnlyOneOfConstraint[H :: T, A, B] {}
}
```

Now we can write (a simplified) `Column` using these constraints :

```
type CompressionEncoding = String

sealed trait ColumnAttribute
case class Default(value: String) extends ColumnAttribute
case class Identity(seed: Int, step: Int) extends ColumnAttribute
case class Encode(encoding: CompressionEncoding) extends ColumnAttribute
case object DistKey extends ColumnAttribute

import OnlyOneOfConstraint._

case class Column[
  Attrs <: HList 
    : <<:[ColumnAttribute]#λ 
    : IsDistinctConstraint 
    : OnlyOneOf[Encode, DistKey.type]#λ
](columnAttributes: Attrs)
```

We now have a compile time guarantee that the attributes are distinct `ColumnAttributes` and will not contain not both a `Encode` and a `DistKey` :

```
Column(DistKey :: Default("s") :: HNil)
// Column[shapeless.::[DistKey.type,shapeless.::[Default,shapeless.HNil]]] = Column(DistKey :: Default(s) :: HNil)

Column(Default("s") :: Encode("a") :: HNil)
// Column[shapeless.::[Default,shapeless.::[Encode,shapeless.HNil]]] = Column(Default(s) :: Encode(a) :: HNil)

Column(DistKey :: Default("s") :: Encode("a") :: HNil)
// <console>:93: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type OnlyOneOfConstraint[shapeless.::[DistKey.type,shapeless.::[Default,shapeless.::[Encode,shapeless.HNil]]],Encode,DistKey.type]
//        Column(DistKey :: Default("s") :: Encode("a") :: HNil)
```

Comment: Thank you @PeterNeyens. This partly answers my question. Partly because seems I formulated it not clearly enough (updated topic). But it satisfies my curiosity and looks like awesome scrap of Shapeless.

Comment: With your updated question, it seems you don't need the `OnlyOneOf` constraint and just need the `LUB` and `IsDistinct`.